# How to format the Timestamp 'new Date()' into Singapore time zone in google apps script?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

I have a code in google apps script which print the timestamp when certain conditions are fulfilled. The code is shown as below:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart == 16 && e.range.rowStart >= 12) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Transmit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  } else if (e.range.columnStart == 14 && e.range.rowStart >= 20) {
    if (e.value == 'Transmit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

For your information, when I'm using the google sheet, it is based on Singapore time zone, but I think other people from different time zone will be different from me.

The goal I want to achieve is to fix the time zone (based on Singapore time zone) for all the user (come from different countries and different time zone) of these google sheet regardless of their time zone setting in their google sheet. I'm trying to include it in `setNumberFormat` but seems like there is no parameter for this function. I'm not sure whether Singapore time zone can be achieved, if not, then at the very least based on New York time zone (since New York is more common?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

You should use the [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) method and specify the timezone of `Singapore`.

Here is a list of all [timezone IDs](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats#locales) you can use for your purpose and the id in your case would be `Asia/Singapore`.

Therefore, this will give you the corrent format and datetime for Singapore:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

**or** given that the timezone in Singapore is `GMT+8` you can use that directly:

```
const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+8', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  if (e.range.columnStart == 16 && e.range.rowStart >= 12) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Transmit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  } else if (e.range.columnStart == 14 && e.range.rowStart >= 20) {
    if (e.value == 'Transmit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```